# Is a custom, static, HTML/CSS website safe enough?

Tags: jquery, html, css, security, web

I'm currently hosting a Wordpress-website for a customer, but have gotten better at frontend dev, and would like to make a much simpler, and more customizable version myself.

The website is mostly static (there will be one, max two blog posts per month), and I think the ability to customize the appearance is more important than a CMS.

I'm pretty sure the security setup the server hosting the website is using is up to par, but I'm not sure if you could "inject" or otherwise tamper with a simple HTML/CSS/Jquery/JS website not run via eg. Wordpress?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not hard to customize child theme. Output is still html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a static website tends to be safer.

It mostly comes down to platform security in this case. e.g.

- Are unneeded services disabled? e.g. telnet
- Are other ports running secure configurations? e.g. SSH is configured with public key authentication, FTP isn't used unless via FTPS.
- Strong passwords are used for management.
- Web server has dynamic handlers and CGI disabled.
- Patches are regularly applied.

It would probably be worth vulnerability scanning the system on a regular basis too - both infrastructure and web, although I wouldn't expect any significant findings from the latter if indeed dynamic content is disabled at server level.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, I guess it mostly depends on your server and server application security configurations (e.g. Firewall, .htacess).